# INSERT INTO & LAST_INSERT_ID inside Query inside function

Tags: php, function, mysqli, insert-into, last-insert-id

Background: This is the first time I've posted a question here, but I have learned a lot from reading others' questions and answers and I really appreciate all of your help!  I have spent several hours researching this problem and can't find a solution that works for me.  The example below is from the [MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) and thus far, seems to be the most reliable.

Goal: Ultimately, I want to link the user id from the registration form (foo for now) database to other databases (foo2 for now).  I THINK I understand the INSERT INTO and the LAST_INSERT_ID and have tried many example I've read here.  Assuming my code for that is correct (which it might not be), I think my question is regarding the syntax and code outside of that area (the entire function createRows).  Do I need two $query or just the one?  Many examples I've seen don't show the query parts or code beyond just the INSERT INTO statements and that's what I need to see.

Problem: I run this code and don't get any errors.  However, data is only going into table foo2, completely skipping/bypassing table foo, which remains completely empty.

```
function createRows(){
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        global $connection;
        $text = $_POST['text'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO foo (id,text) VALUES(NULL,'$text')";
        $query = "INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$text')";  

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Query FAILED' . mysqli_error($connection));
        } else {
            echo "Success! New record created.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not executing the first query.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code with this :

```
function createRows(){
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        global $connection;
        $text = $_POST['text'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO foo (id,text) VALUES(NULL,'$text')";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Query FAILED' . mysqli_error($connection));
        } else {
            $last = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
            $query1 = "INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text) VALUES($last,'$text')"; 
            mysqli_query($connection, $query1); 
            echo "Success! New record created.";
        }
    }
}
```

Also i'm confused with your first query.Why are you inserting `null` value in you `id` field? If your `id` is primary key then it should not be null.Also if you've assigned auto increment to it then you dont need to insert `null` values in it. In this case your first query will be :

```
"INSERT INTO foo (text) VALUES('$text')";
```

> Side note : Your query is unsafe. Read this
>   [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO foo (id,text) VALUES(NULL,'$text')";
$query = "INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$text')";
```

Your second query is overwriting the first query. Either execute them one at a time or put them in separate variables (example blow).

```
$queryOne = "INSERT INTO foo (id,text) VALUES(NULL,'$text')";
$queryTwo = "INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$text')";
```